# Is there a way to accommodate multiple nominal datasets in one-class classification with KDE?

Tags: time-series, kernel-smoothing

I have 50 sets of time series data, which are collected from 50 'good' runs of the fabrication process, and I would like to utilize all of these nominal datasets to train my model.
From what I`ve learned, in KDE the underlying nominal probability distribution is estimated by using just a single nominal dataset. Is there any method that allows me to use all of the available nominal data rather than just a single run?